# how to reset a filter by leaving it empty?

Tags: angularjs

I have a filter on a list :

```
<input ng-model="searchFileName" />
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="file in folders | filter:searchFileName">
        <td><a ng-click="openFolder(file.name)">{{ file.name }}</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I would like to clear searchFileName value when I click on a result.

This is openFolder function :

```
$scope.openFolder = function(name) {
    $scope.searchFileName = null;

    $http.jsonp($scope.server + '?open=' + encodeURIComponent($scope.buildTreePath()) + '&callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function(data){ 
        $scope.folders = data;
    });
}
}
```

I can't empty my filter field, it doesn't work... Where am I wrong ?

Comment: try put `$scope.searchFileName = null;` inside success callback right near `$scope.folders = data;`

Answer (score 2):

just use:

```
  $scope.openFolder = function(name) {

    $scope.searchFileName = null;
  }
```

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('fCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.folders = [

    {
      name: "Ala"
    }, {
      name: "Ata"
    }, {
      name: "Ara"
    }, {
      name: "Ama"
    }

  ];

  $scope.openFolder = function(name) {

    $scope.searchFileName = null;
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="fCtrl">

    <input ng-model="searchFileName" />
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="file in folders | filter:searchFileName">
        <td><a ng-click="openFolder(file.name)">{{ file.name }}</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I edited my question, because maybe the jsonp call is more important that I thought. I think this is why my result list stays empty, because filter is still applying after ajax update, and maybe the filter value can not be null...

Comment: i can see your solution is working, but not in my case. I should reset filtered results & filter field, but don't know how to process.

Comment: @emurb please see here  http://jsfiddle.net/oj57g82a/2/ it looks like your   $http.jsonp not returning any data